# Recursively send list variables to the global environment

Tags: r, recursion

Consider the following nested list, `nest`.

```
nest <- list(
    A = list(w = 1:5, x = letters[1:5]),
    B = list(y = 6:10, z = LETTERS[1:5])
)
```

I'd like to send all the individual variables in `nest` to the global environment. That is, the lists `A` and `B`, and the vectors `w`, `x`, `y`, and `z` should all go to the global environment.  Here are a few of my tries along with their results.  Notice that all of these only send *some* of the variables to the global environment.

```
list2env(nest, .GlobalEnv)
ls()
# [1] "A"    "B"    "nest"
list2env(unlist(nest, recursive = FALSE), .GlobalEnv)
ls()
# [1] "A.w"  "A.x"  "B.y"  "B.z"  "nest"
lapply(nest, list2env, envir = .GlobalEnv)
ls()
# [1] "nest" "w"    "x"    "y"    "z"   
with(nest, list2env(mget(ls()), .GlobalEnv))
ls()
# [1] "A"    "B"    "nest"
```

I also tried other recursive possibilities and got errors because when `list2env` hits the bottom of the list, it finds that `x` is not a list.

```
rapply(nest, list2env, envir = .GlobalEnv)
# Error in (function (x, envir = NULL, parent = parent.frame(), 
#   hash = (length(x) >  : first argument must be a named list
with(nest, {
    obj <- mget(ls())
    do.call(list2env, c(obj, envir = .GlobalEnv))
})
# Error in (function (x, envir = NULL, parent = parent.frame(), 
#     hash = (length(x) >  : unused arguments (A = list(w = 1:5, 
#     x = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")), B = list(y = 6:10, 
#     z = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")))
```

How can I recursively call `list2env` so that all variables go to the global environment?  From a fresh R session, `ls()` would result in

```
# [1] "A" "B" "nest" "w" "x" "y" "z"
```

I've also experimented with `local` and am having the same problem.

Comment: I thought rapply would be the go-to. I can't get it to work either

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a recursive function. Not elegant but it appears to work:

```
nest <- list(A = list(w = 1:5, x = letters[1:5]),
             B = list(y = 6:10, z = LETTERS[1:5]))

test <- function(x) {
    if(is.list(x)) { 
        list2env(x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
        lapply(x, test)
    }
}

test(nest)
ls()
# [1] "A"    "B"    "nest" "test" "w"    "x"    "y"    "z"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `rrapply` in the `rrapply`-package (extended version of base-`rapply`):

```r
library(rrapply)

nest <- list(
  A = list(w = 1:5, x = letters[1:5]),
  B = list(y = 6:10, z = LETTERS[1:5])
)

ls()
#> [1] "nest"

out <- rrapply(
  nest, 
  classes = c("list", "ANY"),
  f = function(x, .xname) assign(.xname, x, envir = .GlobalEnv), 
  how = "recurse"
)

ls()
#> [1] "A"    "B"    "nest" "w"    "x"    "y"    "z"
```

Here, the content of each node (`x`) is assigned to its name (`.xname`) in the global environment. `how = "recurse"` continues recursion after application of the `f` function to each node in the nested list.